# How to run multiple setups in one setup exe

Tags: batch-file, installation

I got two setup exe files that needs to be installed in correct order; setup1.exe first, then setup2.exe. In addition, I also have to run a batch script after setup2.exe is finished.

How can I do this the easiest way?

Comment: I'd write a batch file that executes all the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what level of expertise you're at, so I'm aiming low.

Type the following into Notepad:

```
@echo off
setup1.exe
setup2.exe
call "batch script.bat"
```

Then `Click File` -> `Save As`
Type `%userprofile%\Desktop\MainSetup.bat`
Click -> `OK`

Next Click -> `Start`
Type `CMD.EXE` -> Press `[ENTER]`
Wait for the black command prompt to appear.
Type `CD %userprofile%\Desktop` -> Press `[ENTER]`
Type `DIR MainSetup.*` -> Press `[ENTER]`

If you see a file named `MainSetup.bat.txt`:
Type `REN MainSetup.bat.txt MainSetup.bat` -> Press `[ENTER]`

Now `MainSetup.bat` is ready to be moved to where ever you want it.  If `setup1.exe` `setup2.exe` and `batch script.bat` are in the `PATH`, then you can use it anywhere, including your Desktop (Where it is right now). If not then you will either want to place `MainSetup.bat` in the same directory as the other three, or change the `MainSetup.bat` to reflect their locations. (In Example, change `setup1.exe` to something like this `"C:\Program Files\Program\setup1.exe"`)