# Install two setup in one click

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

I have two setup files i want to make them in one set up that user click on one setup 2nd one run automatically...
like I have setup1.exe and setup2.exe how to create a setup which will run both of them setup one after one in one setup installation.
I have created both setups in visual studio 2010 > Other projects > setup and deployment.

Comment: I think this might help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275978/hwo-to-run-multiple-setups-in-one-setup-exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a batch file as below:

filename -> `installation.bat`

```
setup1.exe
setup2.exe
```

whenever you run `installation.bat` file it will run `setup1.exe` and `setup2.exe`.

> Steps to be followed for creating batch file:

**Step1:**  open notepad.

**Step2:**  enter your commands as below:

```
setup1.exe
setup2.exe
```

**Step3:** save as => `installation.bat`

Note: here extension should be `.bat` (batch file)

**Step4:** now if you double click the `installation.bat` it will run th both setup1.exe and setup2.exe.

Note: you need to save `installation.bat` where both `setup1.exe` and `setup2.exe` are located.

Comment: How to create a batch file can you please define further ?
Thanks.

Comment: @SaadSheikh: see my edited answer, please let me know if you need further information.

Comment: Dear can please tell me that how can we do this work from setup and deployment?